# Speedometer using HTML5 and websocket

Tags: javascript, html

Hi all i developed a speedometer using javascript and i have given a button and a textfeild in which if we give some values on text feild the needle in the speedometer will move. Now i also created a websocket and i want to move the neddle dyanmically using the websocket server. The thing is the websocket code is working fine but i cant move the needle dynamically using the web socket. So, can anyone please help me out with code. this is the code for speedometer.So guys please help me to move the needle on the speedometer dynamically using the websocket.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    // this function is strict...
}());
var iCurrentSpeed = 20,
    iTargetSpeed = 20,
    bDecrement = null,
    job = null;

function degToRad(angle) {
    // Degrees to radians
    return ((angle * Math.PI) / 180);
}

function radToDeg(angle) {
    // Radians to degree
    return ((angle * 180) / Math.PI);
}

function drawLine(options, line) {
    // Draw a line using the line object passed in
    options.ctx.beginPath();
    // Set attributes of open
    options.ctx.globalAlpha = line.alpha;
    options.ctx.lineWidth = line.lineWidth;
    options.ctx.fillStyle = line.fillStyle;
    options.ctx.strokeStyle = line.fillStyle;
    options.ctx.moveTo(line.from.X,
        line.from.Y);
    // Plot the line
    options.ctx.lineTo(
        line.to.X,
        line.to.Y
    );
    options.ctx.stroke();
}

function createLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY, fillStyle, lineWidth, alpha) {
    // Create a line object using Javascript object notation
    return {
        from: {
            X: fromX,
            Y: fromY
        },
        to: {
            X: toX,
            Y: toY
        },
        fillStyle: fillStyle,
        lineWidth: lineWidth,
        alpha: alpha
    };
}

function drawOuterMetallicArc(options) {
    /* Draw the metallic border of the speedometer 
     * Outer grey area
     */
    options.ctx.beginPath();
    // Nice shade of grey
    options.ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(127,127,127)";
    // Draw the outer circle
    options.ctx.arc(options.center.X,
        options.center.Y,
        options.radius,
        0,
        Math.PI,
        true);
    // Fill the last object
    options.ctx.fill();
}

function drawInnerMetallicArc(options) {
    /* Draw the metallic border of the speedometer 
     * Inner white area
     */
    options.ctx.beginPath();
    // White
    options.ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    // Outer circle (subtle edge in the grey)
    options.ctx.arc(options.center.X,
        options.center.Y, (options.radius / 100) * 90,
        0,
        Math.PI,
        true);
    options.ctx.fill();
}

function drawMetallicArc(options) {
    /* Draw the metallic border of the speedometer
     * by drawing two semi-circles, one over lapping
     * the other with a bot of alpha transparency
     */
    drawOuterMetallicArc(options);
    drawInnerMetallicArc(options);
}

function drawBackground(options) {
    /* Black background with alphs transparency to
     * blend the edges of the metallic edge and
     * black background
     */
    var i = 0;
    options.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
    options.ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    // Draw semi-transparent circles
    for (i = 170; i < 180; i++) {
        options.ctx.beginPath();
        options.ctx.arc(options.center.X,
            options.center.Y,
            i,
            0,
            Math.PI,
            true);
        options.ctx.fill();
    }
}

function applyDefaultContextSettings(options) {
    /* Helper function to revert to gauges
     * default settings
     */
    options.ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    options.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    options.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    options.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
}

function drawSmallTickMarks(options) {
    /* The small tick marks against the coloured
     * arc drawn every 5 mph from 10 degrees to
     * 170 degrees.
     */
    var tickvalue = options.levelRadius - 8,
        iTick = 0,
        gaugeOptions = options.gaugeOptions,
        iTickRad = 0,
        onArchX,
        onArchY,
        innerTickX,
        innerTickY,
        fromX,
        fromY,
        line,
        toX,
        toY;
    applyDefaultContextSettings(options);
}

function drawLargeTickMarks(options) {
    /* The large tick marks against the coloured
     * arc drawn every 10 mph from 10 degrees to
     * 170 degrees.
     */
    var tickvalue = options.levelRadius - 8,
        iTick = 0,
        gaugeOptions = options.gaugeOptions,
        iTickRad = 0,
        innerTickY,
        innerTickX,
        onArchX,
        onArchY,
        fromX,
        fromY,
        toX,
        toY,
        line;
    applyDefaultContextSettings(options);
    tickvalue = options.levelRadius - 2;
    // 10 units (major ticks)
    for (iTick = 50; iTick < 145; iTick += 20) {
        iTickRad = degToRad(iTick);
        /* Calculate the X and Y of both ends of the
         * line I need to draw at angle represented at Tick.
         * The aim is to draw the a line starting on the
         * coloured arc and continueing towards the outer edge
         * in the direction from the center of the gauge.
         */
        onArchX = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.cos(iTickRad) * tickvalue);
        onArchY = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.sin(iTickRad) * tickvalue);
        innerTickX = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.cos(iTickRad) * gaugeOptions.radius);
        innerTickY = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.sin(iTickRad) * gaugeOptions.radius);
        fromX = (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius) + onArchX;
        fromY = (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius) + onArchY;
        toX = (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius) + innerTickX;
        toY = (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius) + innerTickY;
        // Create a line expressed in JSON
        line = createLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY, "rgb(127,127,127)", 3, 0.6);
        // Draw the line
        drawLine(options, line);
    }
}

function drawTicks(options) {
    /* Two tick in the coloured arc!
     * Small ticks every 5
     * Large ticks every 10
     */
    drawSmallTickMarks(options);
    drawLargeTickMarks(options);
}

function drawTextMarkers(options) {
    /* The text labels marks above the coloured
     * arc drawn every 10 mph from 10 degrees to
     * 170 degrees.
     */
    var innerTickX = 0,
        innerTickY = 0,
        iTick = 0,
        gaugeOptions = options.gaugeOptions,
        iTickToPrint = 80;
    applyDefaultContextSettings(options);
    // Font styling
    options.ctx.font = 'italic 10px sans-serif';
    options.ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
    options.ctx.beginPath();
    // Tick every 20 (small ticks)
    for (iTick = 50; iTick < 145; iTick += 20) {
        innerTickX = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.cos(degToRad(iTick)) * gaugeOptions.radius);
        innerTickY = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.sin(degToRad(iTick)) * gaugeOptions.radius);
        // Some cludging to center the values (TODO: Improve)
        if (iTick <= 10) {
            options.ctx.fillText(iTickToPrint, (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickX, (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickY + 5);
        } else if (iTick < 50) {
            options.ctx.fillText(iTickToPrint, (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickX - 5, (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickY + 5);
        } else if (iTick < 90) {
            options.ctx.fillText(iTickToPrint, (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickX, (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickY);
        } else if (iTick === 90) {
            options.ctx.fillText(iTickToPrint, (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickX + 4, (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickY);
        } else if (iTick < 145) {
            options.ctx.fillText(iTickToPrint, (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickX + 10, (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickY);
        } else {
            options.ctx.fillText(iTickToPrint, (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickX + 15, (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickY + 5);
        }
        // MPH increase by 10 every 20 degrees
        iTickToPrint += Math.round(2160 / 9);
    }
    options.ctx.stroke();
}

function drawSpeedometerPart(options, alphaValue, strokeStyle, startPos) {
    /* Draw part of the arc that represents
     * the colour speedometer arc
     */
    options.ctx.beginPath();
    options.ctx.globalAlpha = alphaValue;
    options.ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    options.ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
    options.ctx.arc(options.center.X,
        options.center.Y,
        options.levelRadius,
        Math.PI + (Math.PI / 360 * startPos),
        0 - (Math.PI / 360 * 10),
        false);
    options.ctx.stroke();
}

function drawSpeedometerColourArc(options) {
    /* Draws the colour arc.  Three different colours
     * used here; thus, same arc drawn 3 times with
     * different colours.
     * TODO: Gradient possible?
     */
    var startOfGreen = 100,
        endOfGreen = 180,
        endOfOrange = 220,
        endofRed = 260;
    drawSpeedometerPart(options, 1.0, "rgb(82, 240, 55)", startOfGreen);
    drawSpeedometerPart(options, 0.9, "rgb(198, 111, 0)", endOfGreen);
    drawSpeedometerPart(options, 0.9, "rgb(255, 0, 0)", endOfOrange);
    drawSpeedometerPart(options, 1.0, "rgb(0,0, 0,2)", endofRed);
}

function drawNeedleDial(options, alphaValue, strokeStyle, fillStyle) {
    /* Draws the metallic dial that covers the base of the
     * needle.
     */
    var i = 0;
    options.ctx.globalAlpha = alphaValue;
    options.ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    options.ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
    options.ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;
    // Draw several transparent circles with alpha
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        options.ctx.beginPath();
        options.ctx.arc(options.center.X,
            options.center.Y,
            i,
            0,
            Math.PI,
            true);
        options.ctx.fill();
        options.ctx.stroke();
    }
}

function convertSpeedToAngle(options) {
    /* Helper function to convert a speed to the 
     * equivelant angle.
     */
    var iSpeed = (options.speed / 10),
        iSpeedAsAngle = ((iSpeed * 20) + 10) % 180;
    // Ensure the angle is within range
    if (iSpeedAsAngle > 180) {
        iSpeedAsAngle = iSpeedAsAngle - 180;
    } else if (iSpeedAsAngle < 0) {
        iSpeedAsAngle = iSpeedAsAngle + 180;
    }
    return iSpeedAsAngle;
}

function drawNeedle(options) {
    /* Draw the needle in a nice read colour at the
     * angle that represents the options.speed value.
     */
    var iSpeedAsAngle = convertSpeedToAngle(options),
        iSpeedAsAngleRad = degToRad(iSpeedAsAngle),
        gaugeOptions = options.gaugeOptions,
        innerTickX = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.cos(iSpeedAsAngleRad) * 20),
        innerTickY = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.sin(iSpeedAsAngleRad) * 20),
        fromX = (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius) + innerTickX,
        fromY = (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius) + innerTickY,
        endNeedleX = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.cos(iSpeedAsAngleRad) * gaugeOptions.radius),
        endNeedleY = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.sin(iSpeedAsAngleRad) * gaugeOptions.radius),
        toX = (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius) + endNeedleX,
        toY = (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius) + endNeedleY,
        line = createLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY, "rgb(255,0,0)", 5, 0.6);
    drawLine(options, line);
    // Two circle to draw the dial at the base (give its a nice effect?)
    drawNeedleDial(options, 0.6, "rgb(127, F27, 127)", "rgb(255,255,255)");
    drawNeedleDial(options, 0.2, "rgb(127, 127, 127)", "rgb(127,127,127)");
}

function buildOptionsAsJSON(canvas, iSpeed) {
    /* Setting for the speedometer 
     * Alter these to modify its look and feel
     */
    var centerX = 210,
        centerY = 210,
        radius = 140,
        outerRadius = 200;
    // Create a speedometer object using Javascript object notation
    return {
        ctx: canvas.getContext('2d'),
        speed: iSpeed,
        center: {
            X: centerX,
            Y: centerY
        },
        levelRadius: radius - 10,
        gaugeOptions: {
            center: {
                X: centerX,
                Y: centerY
            },
            radius: radius
        },
        radius: outerRadius
    };
}

function clearCanvas(options) {
    options.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    applyDefaultContextSettings(options);
}

function draw() {
    /* Main entry point for drawing the speedometer
     * If canvas is not support alert the user.
     */
    console.log('Target: ' + iTargetSpeed);
    console.log('Current: ' + iCurrentSpeed);
    var canvas = document.getElementById('tutorial'),
        options = null;
    // Canvas good?
    if (canvas !== null && canvas.getContext) {
        options = buildOptionsAsJSON(canvas, iCurrentSpeed);
        // Clear canvas
        clearCanvas(options);
        // Draw the metallic styled edge
        drawMetallicArc(options);
        // Draw thw background
        drawBackground(options);
        // Draw tick marks
        drawTicks(options);
        // Draw labels on markers
        drawTextMarkers(options);
        // Draw speeometer colour arc
        drawSpeedometerColourArc(options);
        // Draw the needle and base
        drawNeedle(options);
    } else {
        alert("Canvas not supported by your browser!");
    }
    if (iTargetSpeed == iCurrentSpeed) {
        clearTimeout(job);
        return;
    } else if (iTargetSpeed < iCurrentSpeed) {
        bDecrement = true;
    } else if (iTargetSpeed > iCurrentSpeed) {
        bDecrement = false;
    }
    if (bDecrement) {
        if (iCurrentSpeed - 10 < iTargetSpeed)
            iCurrentSpeed = iCurrentSpeed - 1;
        else
            iCurrentSpeed = iCurrentSpeed - 5;
    } else {
        if (iCurrentSpeed + 10 > iTargetSpeed)
            iCurrentSpeed = iCurrentSpeed + 1;
        else
            iCurrentSpeed = iCurrentSpeed + 5;
    }
    job = setTimeout("draw()", 5);
}

function drawWithInputValue() {
    var txtSpeed = document.getElementById('txtSpeed');
    if (txtSpeed !== null) {
        iTargetSpeed = txtSpeed.value;
        // Sanity checks
        if (isNaN(iTargetSpeed)) {
            iTargetSpeed = 20;
        } else if (iTargetSpeed < 20) {
            iTargetSpeed = 20;
        } else if (iTargetSpeed > 60) {
            iTargetSpeed = 60;
        }
        job = setTimeout("draw()", 5);
    }
}
```

and this is the code for websocket

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jeff Test HTML5 WebSocket</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script src="speed.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="messageinput"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="openSocket();" >Open</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="drawWithInputValue();" ></button>
            <button type="button" onclick="closeSocket();" >Close</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Server responses get written here -->
        <div id="messages"></div>

        <!-- Script to utilise the WebSocket -->
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var webSocket;
            var messages = document.getElementById("messages");

            function openSocket(){
                // Ensures only one connection is open at a time
                if(webSocket !== undefined && webSocket.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSED){
                   writeResponse("WebSocket is already opened.");
                    return;
                }
                // Create a new instance of the websocket
                webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8181/");

                /**
                 * Binds functions to the listeners for the websocket.
                 */
                webSocket.onopen = function(event){
                    // For reasons I can't determine, onopen gets called twice
                    // and the first time event.data is undefined.
                    // Leave a comment if you know the answer.
                    if(event.data === undefined)
                        return;

                    writeResponse(event.data);
                };

                webSocket.onmessage = function(event){
                    writeResponse(event.data);
                };

                webSocket.onclose = function(event){
                    writeResponse("Connection closed");
                };
            }

            /**
             * Sends the value of the text input to the server
             */
            function send(){
                var text = document.getElementById("messageinput").value;
                webSocket.send(text);
            }

            function closeSocket(){
                webSocket.close();
            }
```

Comment: I think you might have missed adding some code above. How does the response from  the websocket call the draw function?

Comment: function writeResponse(text){
                messages.innerHTML += "<br/>" + text;

 
 
            }
           
        </script>

<iframe src="canvas.html">
       
    </body>
</html>

Comment: function writeResponse(text){
                messages.innerHTML += "<br/>" + text;

 
 
            }
           
        </script>

<iframe src="canvas.html">
       
    </body>
</html> //this is the code i forgot to add in the websocket html. this is the code that will give the response to the server. Here i need to call the function drawWithInputValue() so that needle can move dynamically

Answer (score 0):

}

```
        function writeResponse(text){
            messages.innerHTML += "<br/>" + text;



        }

    </script>
```

```
</body>
```

This is the code i missed at the end of the web socket code.

Answer (score 0):

So the best i can tell, the only thing you need to get working is somehow trigger the canvas draw when a websocket message is delivered. I made some changes to the code you provided just so its complete, you have some things missing like the canvas and correct text input id, and created a jsfiddle with it. Essentiall all you have to change is the onmessage eventhandler and the drawWithInputValue function, to something like :

```
webSocket.onmessage = function(event){
  if(event.data.type == "speed"){
     drawWithInputValue(event.data.value);
  }
  writeResponse(event.data);
};

function drawWithInputValue(txtSpeed) {
    if (txtSpeed !== null) {
        iTargetSpeed = txtSpeed.value;
        // Sanity checks
        if (isNaN(iTargetSpeed)) {
            iTargetSpeed = 20;
        } else if (iTargetSpeed < 20) {
            iTargetSpeed = 20;
        } else if (iTargetSpeed > 60) {
            iTargetSpeed = 60;
        }
        job = setTimeout("draw()", 5);
    }
}

function drawWithInputValueLocal(){
     var txtSpeed = document.getElementById('messageinput');
   drawWithInputValue(txtSpeed)
}
```

Now in your onclick handler in your draw button, just change it to this:

```
 <button type="button" onclick="drawWithInputValueLocal();" >Draw</button>
```

So now when your websocket server sends a message in the format like:

```
{
   type : 'speed',
   value : 30
}
```

The onmessage event handler will check for that message type, then send the value over to the drawInputValue function.

On a final note, i'm not entirely sure why you have this closure at the top of your code seemingly doing nothing:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    // this function is strict...
}());
```

If you want to make your code modular, you'll need to put all your variables and functions inside it, then export it to be used by your page.

https://jsfiddle.net/wbotr9pw/23/